# Stripping directory paths to get file names

Tags: shell-script, filenames, file-descriptors, strip

What I am doing is converting mp3's with LAME. I already have an old script I wrote that works but I want to add to it this ability--to no longer delete the file but instead save it in a new root folder with sub-directories that match the using the path that it is already in.

This is the code I got off the Internet that I am using in my script to get the path:

```
 c=$FILENAME
 xpath=${c%/*} 
 xbase=${c##*/}
 xfext=${xbase##*.}
 xpref=${xbase%.*}
 path=${xpath}
 pref=${xpref}
 ext=${xfext}
```

The `xpath` and `path` give me the directory structure `/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/`

Using that technique, how do I script this to get just the band-folder into a separate variable and the album-folder into a separate variable?

Then I can use them to create  new folders keeping all the mp3s in band album order to put them into a different root folder; this would eliminate me from having to move them myself so the next time I run my script I will not re-sample them again because they will no longer be in the working directoy path/folders and still have a back up copy of my files just in case.

Comment: I personally am shying away from shellscripts, and converting my scripts into Python. Usually they become much more readable, and thus maintainable in the future. Yes, it's a lot of work, and still ongoing, but even partway through I already enjoyed the benefits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When referring to `$c` if by *filename* you mean full-path to file then this job is really very easy. There are a few ways to do it.

Using just POSIX shell globs and parameter expansion you can do:

```
c='/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/music-file.mp3'
file=${c##*/}
album=${c#*"${c%/*/"$file"}"/}
band=${c#*"${c%/*/"$album"}"/}
band=${band%%/*} album=${album%%/*}
```

Basically it works by trimming a string from the tail of the variable and then trimming the results from the head of the variable. In the last line any unwanted remains from the tail are stripped away. It is perhaps easier to understand with real-world data. If you were to wrap the above snippet in a shell with `set -x` enabled, you'd see something along these lines printed to `stderr`:

```
+ c=/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/music-file.mp3
+ file=music-file.mp3
+ album=album-name/music-file.mp3
+ band=band-folder/album-name/music-file.mp3
+ band=band-folder
+ album=album-name
```

Another way you might do this is to use the shell's internal field separator to split the pathname on `/` boundaries.

```
set -f; IFS=/             #disable globbing so as not to gen more filenames
set -- $c                 #set the shell's arg array to split path
shift "$(($#-3))"         #remove all but relevant fields
band=$1 album=$2 file=$3  #assign values
```

Here is some more `set -x` output:

```
+ c=/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/music-file.mp3
+ set -f
+ IFS=/
+ set -- '' home user working-root-directory band-folder album-name music-file.mp3
+ shift 4
+ band=band-folder
+ album=album-name
+ file=music-file.mp3
```

Comment: The `IFS` approach is inventive: nice work.

Comment: @jasonwryan - `$IFS`, `cd -P`, `$PWD`, and `/` are made for each other.

Comment: Yes. I was referring to the total solution (the `shift` and all): clever and illuminating: thanks.

Comment: @jasonwryan - me too. I referred to `cd -P` and the rest because while `"$HOME"//////dir` is a perfectly acceptable pathname, it defies `$IFS`. However, `cd -P "$HOME"/////dir; set -- $PWD` fixes that every time.

Comment: @Costas - your suggested edit would make a welcome comment here, or if it were an answer of its own I would likely upvote it, but I don't like it in the context of this answer. It is difficult enough for me to remember how basic things work and so I always try to keep my solutions as generic as I might - which is why I rejected the edit suggesting this could also be done with shell-specific env vars. also counting args backward is very easily done with `eval` and math expansion - and, as far as I am concerned - fairly well sums up `eval`'s primary purpose - which is translating math to args.

Comment: @mikeserv thank you very much that did it, I have it up and running now - thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

I would hire `zsh` for this job:

```
$ c='/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/filename.mp3'

$ echo $c:h
/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name
$ echo $c:h:h
/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder
$ echo $c:h:h:h
/home/user/working-root-directory

(...)

$ echo $c:t    
filename.mp3
$ echo $c:h:t
album-name
$ echo $c:h:h:t
band-folder

(...)
```

---

If you have to use bash life is harder, you need to use temporary variables:

```
$ c='/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/filename.mp3'

$ x1=${c%/*}
$ echo $x1
/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name
$ x2=${x1%/*}
$ echo $x2
/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder

 (...)

$ y1=${c##*/}
$ echo $y1
filename.mp3
$ y2=${x1##*/}
$ echo $y2
album-name
$ y3=${x2##*/}
$ echo $y3
band-folder

(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous solutions seem overly complicated to me.  The following seems to me to be the simpliest solution.

To get the directory name of a filename strings in bash

```
 dirname "$varcontainingfilename"
```

To get the ONLY the filename from a filename string in bash use

```
 basename "$varcontainingfilename"
```

From this base you should be able to easily do what you want.

Example executing this shell script as script /a/b/c would serve as an example

```
 #!/bin/sh
 set -u
 PATH='/bin:/usr/bin'
 export PATH
 filestring="$1"
 fn=`basename "$filestring"`
 dn=`dirname "$filestring"`
 echo Original File String "$filestring"
 echo Filename is "$fn"
 echo directory is "$dn"
 exit 0
```

Comment: And what if `$filestring` ends in some number of newline characters? Terminating filenames correctly is always problematic when the filename is gathered by the shell from some other process's `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

To make "playing" with variables a little shorter

```
c=/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/music-file.mp3
for var in file album band 
do
  eval "$var=\${c##*/}"
  c=${c%\/${!var}}
done

echo $file $album $band
music-file.mp3 album-name band-folder
```

Other way is to use `read` command

```
IFS=/ read -r band album file  <<< ${c#"${c%/*/*/*}"/}
```

Comment: upvoted for the `read` thing - slick. I don't fully understand the `!var` thing though. What does it do? Though, after a moment's consideration, I do think the `read` thing breaks if there are any `newlines` in the expansion you feed it.

Comment: @mikeserv `${!var}` get the value of variable `$var` Regarding `newlines` I can say that it is very rare case to meet it in file/directory names.

Answer (score 1):

[Zsh is a much more elegant solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164128/6761), but if it is not your shell, you can use`awk`:

```
 printf "%s\n" "$path"
/home/user/working-root-directory/band-folder/album-name/music-file.mp3

band=$(awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2)}' <(printf "%s" "$path"))
printf "%s\n" "$band"
band-folder

album=$(awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}' <(printf "%s" "$path"))
printf "%s\n" "$album"
album-name

file=$(awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <(printf "%s" "$path"))
printf "%s\n" "$file"
music-file.mp3
```

Comment: @Costas Note that using `$NF` breaks if the path includes the file name...