# How do I remove all but the file name (with no extension) from a full file path?

Tags: shell-script, filenames, function

I am presently writing a Bash function to convert all the man pages listed by `equery files <PACKAGE> | grep /usr/share/man/man` (if you are unfamiliar `equery` is a tool used on Gentoo-based systems that is from the `app-portage/gentoolkit` package) into HTML files and one bit of information I need in order to do this is how I can remove everything but the man page's name, without its file extension, from its full path. I realize this phrasing may be confusing so I will explain what I mean by this with an example. Running `equery files sys-apps/portage | grep /usr/share/man/man` gives the output:

```
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/dispatch-conf.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/ebuild.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/egencache.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/emaint.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/emerge.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/emirrordist.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/env-update.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/etc-update.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/fixpackages.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/quickpkg.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man1/repoman.1.bz2
/usr/share/man/man5
/usr/share/man/man5/color.map.5.bz2
/usr/share/man/man5/ebuild.5.bz2
/usr/share/man/man5/make.conf.5.bz2
/usr/share/man/man5/portage.5.bz2
/usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2
```

out of this output say I take the final line `/usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2` (which in the wording I used previously is this man page's full path), for the purpose of my example. Then what I would want to extract from it, within a Bash script, is `xpak.5` (which is its file name, without its extension). How would I do this? I am presently using this Bash function:

```
function manhtmlp {
  for i in `equery files "$1" | grep /usr/share/man/man`
  do
    bzcat $i | mandoc -Thtml > $HOME/GitHub/fusion809.github.io/man/${i}.html
    sudo chmod 777 -R $HOME/GitHub/fusion809.github.io/man/${i}.html
  done
}
```

on the fifth and sixth lines I use the notation `${i}` to indicate where I would like to be able to prune the man page's full path for its file name (without its extension). The user-supplied input (denoted by `$1` in this function) denotes the name of a package, including its category (e.g., it would equal `sys-apps/portage` for the Portage package manager).

**EDIT:** Why this question is distinct from [Stripping directory paths to get file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164125).

This previous question's answers while similar to what I would like do not tell one how to strip file extensions away from file names, only the rest of their path. So in the example of `/usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2` the answer to the aforementioned question would provide one a way to get `xpak.5.bz2` out of this full file path, but not `xpak.5`.

Comment: This may helpful: `basename /usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2 | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'` will return file-name without extension!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

```
line="/usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2"
 # printf "%s\n" "${line##*/}"                                     
 # xpak.5.bz2
file="${line##*/}"
printf "%s\n" "${file%.*}"
xpak.5
```

In Zsh, you can do [nested parameter expansions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

```
printf "%s\n" "${${line##*/}%.*}"
xpak.5
```

Comment: Definitely sounds like you're on the right track, but is there a way to do this in a single line, say with the dummy variable `$i`? Like would `${i##*/%.*}` do the trick?

Comment: @BrentonHorne I think you can play with your `grep` expression, for example this strips out the directory paths: `grep -Po '/usr/share/man/man.*/\K[^/]+\.bz2$'` (hat-tip to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24679492/1144592) on how to use `\K` with the `-Po` flags)

Answer (score 3):

Using **`basename`**:

```
NAME
       basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames

SYNOPSIS
       basename NAME [SUFFIX]
       basename OPTION... NAME...

DESCRIPTION
       Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.  If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.
```

Example:

```
$ file="/usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2"
$ echo "$(basename "$file" .bz2)"
xpak.5
```

---

You can also use `sed` if suffix is unknown:

```
$ file="/usr/share/man/man5/xpak.5.bz2"
$ echo "$(basename "$file" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')"
$ xpark.5
```

Comment: Note, `basename` requires an additional process (as, more obviously, does `sed`)...